# Compile error in solidity stating: Parser Error: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, ide

I am sharing code and [image]image to  show, please check and assist

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Auction {
    
    // Data
    //Structure to hold details of the item
    struct Item {
        uint itemId; // id of the item
        uint[] itemTokens;  //tokens bid in favor of the item
       
    }
    
   //Structure to hold the details of a persons
    struct Person {
        uint remainingTokens; // tokens remaining with bidder
        uint personId; // it serves as tokenId as well
        address addr;//address of the bidder
    }
 
    mapping(address => Person) tokenDetails; //address to person 
    Person [4] bidders;//Array containing 4 person objects
    
    Item [3] public items;//Array containing 3 item objects
    address[3] public winners;//Array for address of winners
    address public beneficiary;//owner of the smart contract
    
    uint bidderCount=0;//counter
    
    //functions

    function Auction() 
    
    public payable{    //constructor
                
        //Part 1 Task 1. Initialize beneficiary with address of smart contract’s owner
        //Hint. In the constructor,"msg.sender" is the address of the owner.
        // ** Start code here. 1 line approximately. **/
        beneficiary = msg.sender;
          //** End code here. **/
        uint[] memory emptyArray;
        items[0] = Item({itemId:0,itemTokens:emptyArray});
        
        //Part 1 Task 2. Initialize two items with at index 1 and 2. 
        // ** Start code here. 2 lines approximately. **/
        uint[] memory emptyArray1;
        items[1] = Item({itemId:1,itemTokens:emptyArray1});
        uint[] memory emptyArray2;
        items[2] = Item({itemId:2,itemTokens:emptyArray2});
        //** End code here**/
    }
    

    function register() 
    
    public payable{
        
        
        bidders[bidderCount].personId = bidderCount;
        
        //Part 1 Task 3. Initialize the address of the bidder 
        /*Hint. Here the bidders[bidderCount].addr should be initialized with address of the registrant.*/

        // ** Start code here. 1 line approximately. **/
        bidders[bidderCount].addr = msg.sender;
        //** End code here. **
        
        bidders[bidderCount].remainingTokens = 5; // only 5 tokens
        tokenDetails[msg.sender]=bidders[bidderCount];
        bidderCount++;
    }
```

Comment: you need another " { " in the end of your code.after that, you see another error like this : 
 "Identifier not found or not unique.
mapping(address => Person) tokenDetails;" , because of problem with your mapping.

Comment: Hey Thank you for replying, i can see the same error that you juts said above. can you suggest me what  to do in order to remove all the bugs so that it can be compiled successfully.

Comment: change your compiler version to 0.4.17 and try again

Answer (score 1):

Your contract seems to be missing one closing `}` from the code

Add that on the last line to fix this issue

[image]